# How to calculate raster area or number of cells for multiple classes in a raster?

Tags: qgis, raster

I have a raster with many classes and I want to know the **area** or the **number of cells** for each class.
I found quite a few posts on this topic (see links below). None of the suggestions matched my wishes. I do not want to convert to vector since my raster is fairly big. I am looking for a tool similar to the summarize functions available for vector data, with a table as output.

The raster is a 32bit float tif with 5 unique values (1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 and 5.0) as classes as a result of classification with QGIS SAGA-Toolbox.

QGIS solutions are preferred. Related posts:

[Calculating raster area?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/176551/raster-area-calculation)

[Calculating area of vegetation in raster file?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40493/calculate-area-of-vegetations-in-a-raster-file?rq=1)

[Calculating area of rasters in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52353/how-to-calculate-the-area-of-rasters-in-qgis?rq=1)

Comment: Can you provide an example (screenshot) of the attribute table of your raster? My guess is that this can be done with python, using cursors.

Comment: I see your point. I have no attribute table available. Probably due to the floating point raster. Maybe this is my problem.

Comment: You can still classify ranges in your raster, either using python or the "Field Calculator".

Comment: In arcgis use raster calculator int(). Result will have a table

Comment: By asking how to do this in two desktop GIS products you are effectively asking two questions which goes against the [Tour].  If you focus your question on one product or other then I think it should be possible to re-open and be more liakely to attract a potential answerer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use GRASS GIS [r.stats](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.stats.html) as a plugin in QGIS or in stand alone GRASS:

> r.stats calculates the area present in each of the categories of user-selected raster map layer(s). Area statistics are given in units of square meters and/or cell Counts

If you need more options like different units use [r.report](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.report.html):

> r.report allows the user to set up a series of report parameters to be applied to a raster map layer, and creates a report.