# Classifying slope (flat, slope, steep, very steep) in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, classification, analysis

I want to classify the slope of the DEM data, by dividing the slope by 4 classes: flat, ramps, steep, very steep.

How to do this with QGIS?

Comment: You want to reclassify the slope raster. See for example this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17712/how-to-perform-raster-reclassification-in-qgis

Comment: A slope raster derived from a DEM must have either the angle or percent of the slope for each individual pixel. You have to decide what range of values are you going to consider a flat, ram steep very steep and reclassify the raster accordingly. After that,in order to get the area, you can convert the reclassified slope raster to vector (polygons).

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 3):

You may apply an on-the-fly reclassification by right-clicking on the layer in the **Layers Panel** and then clicking on `Properties`: from the dialog that appears, go to `Style` and then set these parameters (they are self-explanatory, but you can adapt them following your specific needs):

[image]

Please note that in step No.5 you set `Equal interval` as Mode, but you only do this for the possibility of editing the number of classes (actually, you may choose a different treshold for different categories, even if the `Equal interval` is set).

Finally, click the `Apply` button for applying the changes. You will see something like this:

[image]

as expected.

Instead, if you want to create a reclassification on a **new file**, you may use several tools from the Processing Toolbox (as an example, the **Reclassify values** SAGA tool or the **r.reclass** GRASS module) or directly using the `Raster Calculator` from the `Raster` Menu. Some of these options are well explained in the [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17712/how-to-perform-raster-reclassification-in-qgis) suggested by [@BERA](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/32958/bera) in his [comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/238889/how-to-classify-slope-flat-slope-steep-very-steep-in-qgis#comment372739_238889).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how to calculate the area / percentage area of the class?

Comment: @syafrauf, you can't do it _on-the-fly_ but, for example, you may see [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/199113/how-to-calculate-raster-area-or-number-of-cells-for-multiple-classes-in-a-raster) question for more information. If it is not enough and you don't find other useful results after having searched on GIS SE, the best would be asking a new separate question by describing what exactly you need.

Comment: I would like to classify the DEM data from a sub-district into 4 categories and want to calculate the percentage of each classification. How to do in QGIS ?. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @syafrauf this would be a new separate question (being sure it wasn't already asked before).