# Reclassifying raster layer with certain colors for value ranges in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, style, classification, color

I'm using QGIS. I want a raster layer with 6 different colors each color representing a certain value range (e.g. -1 to 0 red, 0 to 0.2 orange).

In the layer style menu I can only approximate colors.

Comment: Could you [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/241258/edit) your question to include a screenshot of the settings you used please? You could try setting the _Colour interpolation_ option to `Discrete` and setting your _Accuracy_ setting to `Actual (slower)`.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/238898/87487) answer could help.

Comment: Great! Question answered.

Comment: @dadadingo, I'm glad it worked! Since the question I linked doesn't have an accepted answer, I'll repost it here so you can accept it and help future readers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may apply a reclassification by right-clicking on the layer in the **Layers Panel** and then clicking on `Properties`: from the dialog that appears, go to `Style` and then set these parameters (you can adapt them following your specific needs):

[image]

Please note that in step No.5 you set `Equal interval` as Mode, but you only do this for the possibility of editing the number of classes (actually, you may choose a different threshold for different categories, even if the `Equal interval` is set).

Finally, click the `Apply` button for applying the changes.

Instead, if you want to create a reclassification on a **new file**, you may use several tools from the Processing Toolbox (as an example, the **Reclassify values** SAGA tool or the **r.reclass** GRASS module) or directly using the `Raster Calculator` from the `Raster` Menu.

Answer (score 4):

- Go to Layer Properties-->Style menu
- Choose Render Type-->SingleBand Pseudocolor
- In the classes' field enter 6 and press Classify
- In the table on the left change the values and colors as needed.

Comment: But how do I define a range on the table?